# How do I check whether an item exists in Listbox in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

How do I check whether an item already exists in a Listbox?
I am using VS 2008 ASP.NET 3.5 framework C#. I used the following code...

```
 if (ListBox1.Items.Contains(drp_branch.SelectedItem.Value + "-" + txt_acc_no.Text))
 {...}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this...

```
string toMatch = drp_branch.SelectedItem.Value + "-" + txt_acc_no.Text;
ListItem item = ListBox1.Items.FindByText(toMatch);
if (item != null)
{
    //found
}
else
{
    //not found
}
```

Comment: yikes, and what if we don't know the text, only the value? We've got to loop through Items ourselves or use Linq

Answer (score 1):

you can use  this for checking if item is exsits in list box or not ...

```
string checkitem = drp_branch.SelectedItem.Value + "-" + txt_acc_no.Text;

if ((ListBox1.Items.Contains(checkitem) == true))
{
   Response.Write("Item exists");
}
else
{
   Response.Write("Item not   exists");

}
```